# File server access via IIS 8 WebDAV using SSL and cert-based auth

Tags: scripting, ssl-certificate, webdav, iis-8

I have:

- A hole in the corporate firewall allowing me to accept incoming connections on ports 80 and 443
- Exactly one domain name for external web access
- No access to corporate DNS settings
- An onsite Windows Server 2003 domain controller also configured as a Windows file server, relying heavily on NTFS permissions for access control
- An onsite Windows Server 2012 box with IIS 8 installed, *not* joined to the Windows Server 2003's domain, currently running a 3rd party web app that uses plain text logins; app currently appears at http://our.domain.address/appfolder from outside so it's all kinds of insecure
- Virtually no IIS administration experience
- A theoretical understanding of but no practical experience at all with SSL certs
- Easily enough scripting expertise to glue all my requirements together
- Plenty of time

I want to be able to:

- Restrict access to the 3rd party web app to SSL only, with client cert required. Users should still authenticate against the web app with existing usernames and passwords, so no client cert mapping; client cert's purpose is to authenticate the user's machine, not the user.
- Make a couple of shares on our file server externally available via https://our.domain.address/webdav
- Give each of my users a USB memory stick containing

  - a self-signed SSL server cert for our IIS 8 box
  - a unique-per-stick SSL client cert that our IIS 8 box will require on connection
  - a one-click script they can use to install both certs into IE, Firefox and Chrome
  - a script to prompt for a username and password, then map two WebDAV URLs to Windows drive letters. Again, I want IIS to map neither the client cert nor the client's current Windows credentials to Windows server logon credentials; I want my remote users to have to type the same username and password they'd use for Windows logon to an onsite domain-joined workstation, and have IIS pass *those* credentials along to the file server.
- Generate a client cert for each such USB stick by entering an arbitrary ID into a one-dialog script on the IIS 8 box
- Revoke any such client cert by entering the ID used to issue it into another one-dialog script on the IIS 8 box

Could some kind soul either direct me to walkthroughs for:

- Creating a self-signed SSL server cert and configuring IIS 8 for SSL-only operation using that
- Scripting the creation of SSL client certs and configuring IIS 8 to require them for SSL connections (in PowerShell, JScript, VBS, cmd or any mixture)
- Scripting revocation/cancellation/deregistration of SSL client certs on IIS 8
- Setting up WebDAV on IIS 8 with plain text auth over SSL, passing that auth on for access to UNC paths on other LAN-accessible but otherwise unrelated file servers
- Scripting installation of one self-signed server cert and one client cert into IE/Winhttp, Gecko-based browsers, and Webkit-based browsers

or tell me I'm going about this in a boneheaded way because there's something nifty already built into Windows that will do everything I want with two clicks and why don't I just use that? Thanks, all.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I have an idea.

1. Register your own domain name
2. Point the DNS to this IIS server that you have
3. Set up a password protected site that only accepts connections on 443
4. Enable directory browsing
5. Put a bunch of files in there, no index (unless you wanted to share files over a fancy html page)

That is how I would do it.

That way, they are going over HTTPS, they can access the file tree and download things, it is password protected by IIS...

But still, you could just talk to your local administrator about setting something up properly.

Also, you really need to cut down the unnecessary bits of your question. It hurts my eyes.

Comment: Already have the domain name. Need access to the existing file servers, complete with all existing access controls; don't want a requirement to copy files to the web server. We're a primary school, so our internal passwords are squishy-soft, certainly not good enough to stand up to attack if exposed unrestricted to the wider Internet; that's why I want to limit web access to people in possession of client certs I can revoke. And I am the local administrator at this site, just not in charge of the VPN and firewalls upstream of us.